# How to show a page in different languages?

Tags: node.js, internationalization, seo, google-search-console

I use this meta tags to make google crawler know that I have two languages for my site, as suggested here [support.google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/de" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en" />
```

So sometimes the content of `example.com` would be the same as `example.com/de` and sometimes `example.com` would be the same as `example.com/en`.

I use the following code to detect language

```
const lang = (
     getLangFromUrl(req.url) || 
     getLangFromCookies(req.cookies) || 
     getLangFromHeader(req.headers) || 
     'de'
);
```

and google detects `example.com` and `example.com/de` as duplicated pages.

Can you please tell me how should it be correctly done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has mentioned this issue in this link: [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en])

If you prefer to dynamically change content or reroute the user based on language settings, be aware that Google might not find and crawl all your variations. This is because the Googlebot crawler usually originates from the USA. In addition, the crawler sends HTTP requests without setting Accept-Language in the request header.

I hope this will help you

Comment: ok, but what is x-default? I thought its an option to change content dynamically 
 based on language setting or user choice. am I right?

Comment: Default page doesn't target any language or locale; has selectors to let users pick their language and region.

Answer (score 0):

**Handling duplicate pages with multilingual/multi-regional sites**

If you provide similar or duplicate content on different URLs in the same language as part of a multi-regional site (for instance, if both `example.de/` and `example.com/de/` show similar German language content), you should pick a preferred version and use the **rel=canonical** element and **hreflang** tags to make sure that the correct language or regional URL is served to searchers.

You can find here the Google guide to Consolidate duplicate URLs: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en